# How to filter by arbitrary identifiers tabulated in a second data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I often find myself having lists of unique identifiers representing specific experiments I want to analyze. To speed up the process of creating subsets of my data with these experiments, I have taken to storing these lists in separate tables. These combinations of unique identifiers change frequently, depending on the type of data I'm analyzing, and while I know I can write a function like this every time:

```
library(dplyr)
filter_xy <- function(data, look) {
  base <- look %>% mutate(id__ = paste0(x,y)) %>% distinct()
  data %>%
    mutate(id__ = paste0(x,y)) %>%
    filter(id__ %in% base$id__) %>%
    select(-id__)
}
```

I'd like to generalize the above function to work with arbitrary combinations of unique identifiers. That way I can have one function that I always use:

```
filter_id(data, look, x, y)
```

I've been trying to figure this out, but I don't really understand nonstandard evaluation yet. I figure it should be something like this, but I'm not sure.

```
filter_id <- function(data, look, ...) {
  id <- c(...)
  base <- look %>%
    mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(interp( ~ paste0(id))), "id__")) %>%
    distinct()
  data %>%
    mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(interp( ~ paste0(id))), "id__")) %>%
    filter(id__ %in% base$id__) %>%
    select(-id__)
}
```

I'd appreciate any guidance. Below I have formulated some example data:

`lookup.csv`:

```
g,h
a,a
a,b
b,a
b,b
c,a
c,b
c,c
c,d
```

`test.csv`:

```
g,h,x,y
a,a,1,10
a,a,2,8
a,b,1,10
a,b,2,8
a,b,3,7
a,c,1,10
a,c,2,9
a,c,3,8
a,c,4,8
a,d,1,10
a,d,2,9
a,d,3,8
a,e,1,10
a,e,2,10
a,e,3,10
b,a,1,10
b,a,2,3
b,b,1,10
b,b,2,5
b,c,1,10
b,c,2,10
b,c,3,10
b,d,1,10
b,d,2,10
c,a,1,10
c,a,2,8
c,b,1,10
c,b,2,9
c,b,3,8
c,b,4,8
c,c,1,10
c,c,2,4
c,d,1,10
d,a,1,10
d,a,2,9
d,a,3,8
d,b,1,10
d,b,2,10
d,b,3,10
d,c,1,10
d,c,2,9
d,c,3,9
d,d,1,10
d,d,2,10
```

The code I want to write to subset the `test.csv` data to just the columns in the `lookup.csv` data is:

```
lookup <- read_csv("lookup.csv")
test <- read_csv("test.csv")
test %>% filter_id(lookup, g, h)
```

The result should only show rows where there is a match in the `ids` from `lookup.csv`. I can't just filter by `g %in% lookup$g & h %in% lookup$h` because the particular combinations are what I want to select, not two independent conditions.

The special case function would be:

```
filter_gh <- function(data, look) {
  base <- look %>% mutate(id__ = paste0(g,h)) %>% distinct()
  data %>%
    mutate(id__ = paste0(g,h)) %>%
    filter(id__ %in% base$id__)
}
```

with the result:

```
       g     h     x     y
   (chr) (chr) (int) (int)
1      a     a     1    10
2      a     a     2     8
3      a     b     1    10
4      a     b     2     8
5      a     b     3     7
6      b     a     1    10
7      b     a     2     3
8      b     b     1    10
9      b     b     2     5
10     c     a     1    10
11     c     a     2     8
12     c     b     1    10
13     c     b     2     9
14     c     b     3     8
15     c     b     4     8
16     c     c     1    10
17     c     c     2     4
18     c     d     1    10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you really just want to do a `?semi_join` using the correct columns (`g` and `h`):

> **semi_join**
>
> return all rows from x where there are matching values in y,
>   keeping just columns from x.
>
> A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join will
>   return one row of x for each matching row of y, where a semi join will
>   never duplicate rows of x.

For your example, that would be:

```
semi_join(test, lookup, by = c("g", "h"))
#   g h x  y
#1  a a 1 10
#2  a a 2  8
#3  a b 1 10
#4  a b 2  8
#5  a b 3  7
#6  b a 1 10
#7  b a 2  3
#8  b b 1 10
#9  b b 2  5
#10 c a 1 10
#11 c a 2  8
#12 c b 1 10
#13 c b 2  9
#14 c b 3  8
#15 c b 4  8
#16 c c 1 10
#17 c c 2  4
#18 c d 1 10
```

There may be warnings if you stored your data as `factor` variables.

Comment: Much simpler way to think about it.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought of using any of the `*_join` functions.